# Resize JList file elements in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlist, jfilechooser

I have a `JFileChooser`. I am trying to add a zoom feature to the files `JList`.

I would like to change the scale factor of the file name and of the file icon, for each element of the list.

How could we achieve this ?

- Should I make a `custom renderer` like here [JList custom renderer example] (http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jlist-custom-renderer-example)
- or change the list `Model` ?

Comment: A model is only used to hold the data. It does not control how the data is rendered.

Comment: ooh, oki. I feel that the renderer will change the font and the icon size of the items. Is the type of list items `JLabel` ?

Comment: `Is the type of list items JLabel` - I have no idea what the object added to the ListModel is for a file chooser. A guess be a "File" objects. Again the model only stores the data (typically a String). The renderer then takes the data and formats it. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for the basics. There is also a section on creating a custom renderer (although it takes you to the combo box tutorial).

Comment: @KaHinCostner wait... You want to zoom a JFileChooser, or a JList?

Comment: @KaHinCostner Do you want the list cells to have the same size with each other, no matter what the scale, OR do you want independent cell sizes?

Comment: I want to resize the JList that is inside the JFileChooser. I'm good with all cells having the same size ^^

Comment: The `JFileChooser` is not a white-box. There’s not even a guaranty that there is a `JLIst` within it for every look&feel.

Comment: @Holger oh, I kind of took that in consideration. Would you have, perhaps, more informations regarding the `JFileChooser` Components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out some ugly lazy hacks to do it.
It might not be just what you want, but it's a good starting point (and fairly simple):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI;

public class TJFileChooserDemo {

    //Obtains the (first) JList which is found inside the component/container:
    public static JList getFirstJList(final Component component) {
        if (component instanceof JList)
            return (JList) component;
        if (component instanceof Container)
            for (int i=0; i<((Container)component).getComponentCount(); ++i) {
                final JList list = getFirstJList(((Container)component).getComponent(i));
                if (list != null)
                    return list;
            }
        return null;
        //As you can see, it's a bit lazy hack, which has to run for every JFileChooser once at start-up.
    }

    private static final double SCALE_STEP_SIZE = 0.125; //Smaller values of this makes zooming slower. Greater values makes zooming faster.
    private static double scaleFactor = 1;

    public static class TJListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        public TJListCellRenderer() {
            //Ensure every pixel is painted starting from the top-left corner of the label:
            super.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
            super.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
            //We need to do this, because the scaling in paintComponent() is also relative to the top-left corner.
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            //setRenderingHints here? Probably for ANTIALIAS...
            ((Graphics2D)g).scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor); //Let's scale everything that is painted afterwards:
            super.paintComponent(g); //Let's paint the (scaled) JLabel!
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            final Dimension superPrefDim = super.getPreferredSize(); //Handles automatically insets, icon size, text font, etc.
            final double w = superPrefDim.width * scaleFactor, //And we just scale the preferred size.
                         h = superPrefDim.height * scaleFactor; //And we just scale the preferred size.
            return new Dimension((int)w + 5, (int)h + 5); //Add 5 extra pixels to spare.
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
//            System.out.println(value.getClass()); //Something ugly...
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        }
    }

    public static class TJListUI extends BasicListUI {
        @Override
        public void updateLayoutState() {
            super.updateLayoutState(); //Just make the following method public.
            /*Note: this is not really needed here:
            The method could remain protected, but in the case you want this
            code to be a bit more reusable, then you shall make it public.*/
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);

        final TJListUI ui = new TJListUI();

        final JList list = getFirstJList(jfc);
        list.setUI(ui);
        list.setCellRenderer(new TJListCellRenderer());

        final JButton buttonZoomIn = new JButton("Zoom in"),
                      buttonZoomOut = new JButton("Zoom out"),
                      buttonResetZoom = new JButton("Reset zoom");

        buttonZoomIn.addActionListener(e -> {
            scaleFactor = scaleFactor + SCALE_STEP_SIZE;
            ui.updateLayoutState(); //Read the preferred sizes from the cell renderer.
            list.revalidate(); //Update the JScrollPane.
            list.repaint(); //Repaint the list.
        });

        buttonZoomOut.addActionListener(e -> {
            scaleFactor = Math.max(scaleFactor - SCALE_STEP_SIZE, SCALE_STEP_SIZE); //Do not allow underflow.
            ui.updateLayoutState(); //Read the preferred sizes from the cell renderer.
            list.revalidate(); //Update the JScrollPane.
            list.repaint(); //Repaint the list.
        });

        buttonResetZoom.addActionListener(e -> {
            scaleFactor = 1;
            ui.updateLayoutState(); //Read the preferred sizes from the cell renderer.
            list.revalidate(); //Update the JScrollPane.
            list.repaint(); //Repaint the list.
        });

        final JPanel buttons = new JPanel(); //FlowLayout.
        buttons.add(buttonZoomIn);
        buttons.add(buttonZoomOut);
        buttons.add(buttonResetZoom);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        panel.add(jfc, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFileChooser's JList cell sizes demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51176197/6746785) about individually resizable cells of a `JList`.

You can also probably add the `JFileChooser`'s buttons for zooming in/out as an [accessory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAccessory-javax.swing.JComponent-). Read [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddingAccessoryPanels.htm) simple example for how to do it.

Test this code, and I am waiting for comments...

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I realized scaling the text wasn't needed.

To obtain the image files thumbnail, I used the code in [making JFileChooser show image thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096433/making-jfilechooser-show-image-thumbnails) - check BoffinbraiN answer.

Then for scaling :

1) add an `ActionListener` to the buttons of `ThumbnailFileChooser`.

```
public class ZoomListener implements ActionListener {
    private boolean zoomIn = false;
    private IconScaleManager iconScaleManager = null;

    public ZoomListener(boolean zoom, IconScaleManager renderer) {
        zoomIn = zoom;
        iconScaleManager = renderer;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        iconScaleManager.scaleButton(zoomIn);
    }
}
```

2) `ActionListener::actionPerformed()` calls a `scale method` of a `ScaleManager`.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    iconScaleManager.scaleButton(zoomIn);
}
```

3) The `ScaleManager` method changes and update the cells of the `ThumbnailFileChooser's Jlist` (the list is an attribute of the `ScaleManager`)

```
public class IconScaleManager {     
    static final int[] iconScales = new int[]{ 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048 };

    private int scaleIndex = 4;
    private JList fileList = null;

    public IconScaleManager(JList list) {
        fileList = list;
        setFixedCellDimension();
    }

    public void scaleButton(boolean zoomIn) {
        if (zoomIn && scaleIndex < iconScales.length - 1) {
            scaleIndex++;

            setFixedCellDimension();
        } else if (!zoomIn && 0 < scaleIndex) {
            scaleIndex--;

            setFixedCellDimension();
        }
    }

    private void setFixedCellDimension() {
        fileList.setFixedCellWidth(iconScales[scaleIndex]);
        fileList.setFixedCellHeight(iconScales[scaleIndex]);
    }
}
```

Thank you @thanopi57 for your help. I didn't really use what you provided, but I appreciate your support.

Also, I will have to make sure that it works, because there might not be a JList for all `JFileChooser`